# ReactiveUI class and interface disappeared after upgrading

Tags: xamarin.ios, .net-6.0, reactiveui, visual-studio-mac

I'm migrating a Xamarin.iOS project to .Net6. I also upgraded ReactiveUI.Fody Nuget package from 9.8.1 to 19.5.1.
The class ReactiveViewController and interface IActivatable that I was using before now throwing CS0246 error.

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IActivatable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I checked Assembly browser and they weren't there anymore. However I checked ReactiveUI documentation they are not deleted or changed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that ReactiveUI 19.5.1 does not support net6-ios.
Install ReactiveUI 19.4.1 and the references worked as expected.
Note that IActivatable is now IActivatableView as mentioned in other answer.

Answer (score 0):

`IActivatable` is now `IActivatableView` I guess - based on the history https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/commits/0a61f2ab88d3a7e0721c1dc41fed43f30900c011/src/ReactiveUI/Interfaces/IActivatableView.cs

Comment: Thank you, it helps. Seems like I only looked for ReactiveCollectionView and made assumption that they're not changed but actually IActivatable was changed